# SQL multiple join tidy up

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this statement:

```
SELECT board.*,numlikes 
FROM board
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT pins.board_id, COUNT(source_user_id) AS numlikes
    FROM likes 
    INNER JOIN pins ON pins.id = likes.pin_id 
    GROUP BY pins.board_id
) likes ON board.id = likes.board_id
WHERE who_can_tag='' 
ORDER BY numlikes DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

I can then extract rows from `board` using `".$info['board_name']."`.
However, I'm not good with multiple joins and I need to join another table to this besides the `board` and `likes` tables.
The third table is `user` and matches to `board.user_id` with `user.user_id`.

how can I then use this data to extract a username from `user`?

Wouldn't `".$info['username']."` search for the field `username` in the table `board` still?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
SELECT board.*,
    `user`.username,
    numlikes 
FROM board
INNER JOIN `user` ON board.user_id = `user`.user_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT pins.board_id, COUNT(source_user_id) AS numlikes
    FROM likes 
    INNER JOIN pins ON pins.id = likes.pin_id 
    GROUP BY pins.board_id
) likes ON board.id = likes.board_id
WHERE who_can_tag='' 
ORDER BY numlikes DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. I wasn't sure where to place the INNER JOIN